# Dynamic refs inside v-for loop giving error don't appear in DOM. **Provided element is not within a Document**

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using canvas2Html where you i pass the ref of element to take image of element.  i am dynamically assigning the refs to take image of particular divs. The code runs but i am getting the **Provided element is not within a Document**. In Devconsole refs are not appearing too. 
I am really stuck on this one. Any suggestions

https://codesandbox.io/embed/rlo3mmo5zp?fontsize=14

I want the image of signature and initial as output. I am currently getting error. :/

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget that if you use `:ref` inside `v-for` then it becomes an Array - so you should change your code

```
async takeimage(name) {
  let el = this.$refs[name][0]; // <--- use an Array
```

Comment: Thank you. It has solved my issue but i don't understand why can't i just put [1] or [2] instead of [0]

Comment: In your situation, the REF is different on each `v-for` iteration - that is why you have only 1 element in the corresponding Array. If you have had the same REF on each iteration - then you would have ended up with as many elements in the Array for your chosen REF as there were `v-for` iterations.